# how to stop firing an event using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a "OnClick" event and "OnClientClick" event. "OnClientClickEvent" A javascript function 
and "onclick event" runs on server. i want a way to prevent firing this on click event from that javascript function.scenario is like that-

```
asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:AnsCheck()" />
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to stop the server side event?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return AnsCheck()" />
```

**javascript**

```
 funcion AnsCheck(){
    //Based on code and condition you can return
    if(condition){
        return true // will fire server side event
    }
    else{
        return false; // will not fire server event
    }
  }
```

**Or**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return AnsCheck() return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false, in your javascript function, and in the OnClientClick specify a return call.

```
<script>
function AnsCheck()
{
    //do something 

    if (someCondition == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return AnsCheck()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

return false is the answer, for onClientClick in function or in button attributes

```
asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:AnsCheck();return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use `event.off()` method // here event is the object you have passed in the callback function
                        //of event

for example,

```
$( "p" ).off( "click" )
```